# how to create the nscalender and gregorian calender

Tags: iphone

how to create the nscalender and gregorian calendar?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize and use gregorian calendar like:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:1965];
    [comps setMonth:1];
    [comps setDay:6];
    [comps setHour:14];
    [comps setMinute:10];
    [comps setSecond:0];
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *date = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

and the current calendar like:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:1965];
    [comps setMonth:1];
    [comps setDay:6];
    [comps setHour:14];
    [comps setMinute:10];
    [comps setSecond:0];
    NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
```